# How to unit test JSON parsing

Tags: java, android, json, unit-testing

I'm working on an Android app in which I download JSON data from a web service. The class parsing the data looks something like this:

```
public class JsonCourseParser implements CourseParser {

    public Course parseCourse(String courseData) {
        Course result;

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(courseData);

            ...

            result = new Course("foo", "bar");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This builds just fine and it works when I call `parseCourse()` from within my app, but when I try to test this method in a unit test I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at JsonCourseParserTest.initClass(JsonCourseParserTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 16 more
```

It seems that the classes of the `org.json` package which come with the Android Framework are not available in Java by default.

Is there a way I can fix this so I can unit test the classes which parse JSON?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

All you need to do is add the following line to the dependency section in your build.gradle:

```
testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'
```

Note that you also need to use Android Studio **1.1** or higher and at least build tools version **22.0.0** or above for this to work!

`testImplementation` means that the dependency is included as a test dependency will only be used when your project is being compiled for executing unit tests. The supplied jar will not be included in your APK and will only be used to replace the missing classes in the `org.json` package.

Comment: Thanks for this Xaver! I was beginning to think no one else was trying to use Unit Tests with the latest build tools.

Answer (score 19):

*Edit: see updated answer at the end*

I've found the answer to this one. It doesn't solve my problem, but at least it explains *why* there is a problem.

First, I made the faulty assumption that the `JSONObject` (imported from the `org.json` package) was included as a part of the JRE. It isn't - in an Android project, this resides in `android.jar` (classic "duh" moment).

This discovery boosted my self confidence a bit. This could easily be solved by adding a reference to the `android.jar` in my unit test project - or at least so I thought for a brief moment. Doing so only gave me another error when running my test:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:8)
    ...
```

At least this gave me something more to google for. What I found however, wasn't really encouraging (yet another classic "duh" moment)...

This blog describes the problem pretty well: [Why Android isn’t ready for TDD, and how I tried anyway](http://daverog.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/why-android-isnt-ready-for-tdd-and-how-i-tried-anyway/). If you don't bother to read the whole thing, the brief explanation is as follows:

> The problem here is that the
>   android.jar supplied with the SDK is
>   stubbed out with no implementation
>   code. The solution that seems to be
>   expected is that you should run your
>   unit tests on the emulator or a real
>   phone.

When further doing some googling with this in mind, I found several articles, blogs and also questions here on SO regarding the issue. I'll add a few links here at the end, for those that might be looking:

- [android.jar In The SDK Only Has The API And Not The Implementation?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/38c190f33a454c90)
- [Can I use android.os.* libraries in a standalone project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755470/can-i-use-android-os-libraries-in-a-standalone-project)
- [AndroidTesting](https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/)
- [Eclipse + Android + JUnit test references android.os class = NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791650/eclipse-android-junit-test-references-android-os-class-noclassdeffounderror) (not sure why on earth I didn't find this one when I initially wrote my question, I must have been completely lost...)

And there are plenty more if you look around.

There are several suggestions/solution/alternative approaches to unit testing in Android in many of those links, but I won't bother to try to make a good answer based on that (as there is *obviously* way too much I still don't know about Android development). If anybody has any nice tips though, I'll be glad to hear about them :)

***UPDATE:***
After experimenting a bit more, I actually managed to find a working solution to this specific problem. The reason why I didn't try this in the first place, was that I thought I had read somewhere that it would be problematic to include "normal" java libraries in my Android app. I was trying so many different things to get around my problem, so I thought I'd just give this a try as well - and it actually worked! Here is how:

- I downloaded the source for the "real" `org.json` package from here: http://www.json.org/java/index.html
- Next I compiled the source code and packed it together in my own *json.jar*
- I added the newly created *json.jar* to the build path of my project (the main project of my Android application, not the test project)

No changes to my code, no changes to my test, only adding this library. And everything works, both my Android app and my unit tests.

I also tested stepping through the code in debug mode, and when debugging the Android app the `JSONObject` in my `JsonCourseParser` is fetched from the Android SDK (*android.jar*), but when debugging my unit test it is fetched from my own *json.jar*. Not sure if this means that the *json.jar* isn't included when my app is built, or if the runtime intelligently selects the correct library to use. Also not sure if this extra library might have any other effects on my final app. I guess only time will tell...

Comment: thanks for your detailed analysis and description of the problem! And did the time tell you something for this problem?

Comment: Building the jar from source worked for me!  It seems really silly that Android doesn't include this in the SDK somewhere

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Björn Quentin's [Unmock](https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin) Gradle plugin, which allows you to replace stubbed classes in the default android.jar with real versions from another android.jar (e.g. Robolectric).

Comment: `keepStartingWith "org.json."`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I found a better way. The framework [Roboelectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/index.html) does the job. At first I just added the roboelectric.jar as external library (because I don't use Maven) to the build path of my Java JUnit test project and as "class annotation" I added `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`. But then I got a **NoClassDefFoundError: android/net/Uri**. After I still added the android.jar itself used by the corresponding Android project (although the Android library with its android.jar was already a part of my build path), it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact problem in my JSON tests. Your updated answer led me to try a simpler approach, which worked for my project. It allows me to run JUnit tests, using the 'real' org.json JAR, on my non-Android classes from within Eclipse:

1. Download org.json's json.jar from here (or wherever): http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
2. Add a folder 'libs-test' to your project, copy the json.jar file to it
3. In Eclipse open: Run / Run Configurations, select JUnit / *YourTestClass*
4. On the Classpath tab, remove "Google APIs" from Bootstrap entries
5. Click "Add JARs", navigate to /libs-test/json.jar and add it.
6. Click "Close"
7. Run your tests