# Android Studio 1.2.2 - junit - json empty, why?

Tags: java, android, json, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to use a json in an AndroidTestCase, however the JSONObject is always empty, even though I put an element in it. Do I have to do anything special in order to make JSONObjects work in a unit test?

Here's my AndroidTestCase class:

```
public class JSONUtilTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    private JSONObject mJSONSummary;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mJSONSummary = new JSONObject();
        mJSONSummary.put("test", 123);
        assertTrue(mJSONSummary.length() == 1); //assertion error
    }
}
```

My module's build.grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nubank.brunodea"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId "com.nubank.brunodea"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 and when I don't use JSONObjects the tests work.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used the debugger to find out why the length is different?

Comment: @StefanBirkner yes! I think the issue is that in tests, the JSONObject class is a mock class, so it is not really implemented.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the failing test, please.

Comment: The answer for your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35675861/3032209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned JSONObject is only mocked so testing this with the default config does not work. You can either choose to use an external JSON implementation for testing like [json simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) or choose to use another framework which mocks the equivalent classes for you with full functionality like [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) can do.

I personally choose the 2nd option but you should consider that this is a very massive testing environment which might be a bit too oversized for simple JSONObject testing.

See also this answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972592/4310905